# Vaadin gets stuck in loop when using Spring security with a login form

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin 19 + Spring Boot + custom authentication flow

Working: login shown correctly + authentication succeeds + redirect to correct home page URL
Problem: on the homepage the login box is shown again

My implementation is based on https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security

```
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider(userService))
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Require login to access internal pages and configure login form.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Not using Spring CSRF here to be able to use plain HTML for the login page
        http.csrf().disable()
                // Register our CustomRequestCache that saves unauthorized access attempts, so
                // the user is redirected after login.
                .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
                // Restrict access to our application.
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                // Allow all flow internal requests.
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtil::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                // Allow all requests by logged in users.
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                // Configure the login page.
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage(URL_LOGIN).permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(URL_LOGIN_PROCESSING)
                .failureUrl(URL_LOGIN_FAILURE)
                .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                // Configure logout
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl(URL_LOGOUT)
                .logoutSuccessUrl(URL_LOGOUT_SUCCESS);
    }

/**
 * Allows access to static resources, bypassing Spring security.
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            // Vaadin Flow static resources
            "/VAADIN/**",
            // the standard favicon URI
            "/favicon.ico",
            // the robots exclusion standard
            "/robots.txt",
            // style related files, needed here to prevent download of files between login and home
            "/icons/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/styles/**",
            "/sw-runtime-resources-precache.js",
            // web application manifest
            "/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/sw.js",
            "/offline-page.html",
            // (development mode) static resources
            "/frontend/**",
            // (development mode) webjars
            "/webjars/**",
            // (production mode) static resources
            "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**");
}
```

The logging shows repeated calls to CustomAuthenticationProvider to this method:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
```

Could this be a missing user role? Does this need to be configured?

My application worked OK before, when I was first testing with a single fixed account like this:

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.withUsername("username")
            .password("{noop}password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Comment: You didn't copy all the code of the Security Configuration class. The path ignored are important!

Comment: Thanks, good remark, added now to question

Comment: From your question I cannot tell what is wrong. Could you provide the project on GitHub?

Comment: Unfortunately not... and depends on another service to validate the login. Maybe in a pair programming code-with-me-session? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already suspected, problem was a missing ROLE.

In my CustomAuthenticationProvider, I was returning a user like this:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
   var email = authentication.getName();
   var password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
   // Call here to backend to check login
   return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);
}
```

Which actually returns a user which is authenticated=false...

By changing the code to:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
   var email = authentication.getName();
   var password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
   // Call here to backend to check login
   Collection<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
   roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
   return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password, roles);
}
```

the user has authenticated=true, and the Vaadin UI works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you exclude the LoginView in ConfigureUIServiceInitListener.java

```
private void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        if (!LoginView.class.equals(event.getNavigationTarget()) // <--
            && !SecurityUtils.isUserLoggedIn()) { 
            event.rerouteTo(LoginView.class); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that one is there! Thanks for the tip